# How to listen on dirty/pristine status in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I work with angular reactive forms and NgRx store. What I wanna achieve is to store form dirty/pristine status and react on its changes in another component.

I'm familiar with `statusChanges` and `valueChanges` properties of form, which return Observable of appropriate information. Could you please help me to get dirty/pristine status in similar way?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this I am also keen to achieve the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I detect/watch "dirty-status" of an angular2-form in the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39699752/how-can-i-detect-watch-dirty-status-of-an-angular2-form-in-the-right-way)

Answer (score 4):

As we are in JavaScript, we can do a 'sinister' hack, to get hold on `markAsPristine()` and `markAsDirty()` in an event like manner: interept the function call itself!

For example, if you have an Angular FormGroup named `this.formGroup`, then `this.formGroup.markAsPristine` without the paretheses '()' is the function itself, not the call to it!

We can store this function into a constant and overload `this.formGroup.markAsPristine` with a new implementation:

```js
    const oldFuncPristine = this.formGroup.markAsPristine;
    const fg = this.formGroup;

    this.formGroup.markAsPristine = function() {
      oldFuncPristine.apply(fg);
      console.log("formGroup marked PRISTINE");
      // ...other code, e.g. sending events
    };
```

Ok, but why do we need to have the constant `fg`?
Well, we define with `function() {...}` a pure function. This function does not 'see' this in its scope. So we use this not very sophisticated way to let the function know about the FormGroup and about `this`.

There is a better way to pass this to a function, but that's not the topic of this post. If courious, see [blog about bind(), apply(), call()](https://thenewstack.io/mastering-javascript-callbacks-bind-apply-call/)

I hope, that helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I found the solution. The observer of valueChanges can just check form dirty/pristine state. i.e.:

```
this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
    console.log(`Is form dirty?: ${this.myForm.dirty}`);
});
```

Comment: `valueChanges` is called each time the form's control value is changed. You don't need each such call - only the first one (when the form GETS DIRTY). So it's not the best approach you offer. Even though I still don't know other than that or `statusChanges`...

Comment: Neither statusChanges nor valueChanges trigger when explicitly calling myForm.markAsDirty() without modifying a value.